# How to pass 2-D char array to a function?

Tags: c++, arrays

I just create a simple function which takes the 2-D char array as an argument and then just print the values of that 2-D char array.
The function is given below

```
void final_output(char arr[][200]){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++){
            cout << arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

And i call this function as

```
final_output(grid_2);
```

But i face an error

```
error: cannot convert 'char (*)[c]' to 'char (*)[200]' for argument '1' to 'void final_output(char (*)[200])'
final_output(grid_2);
```

I search for different methods to pass the 2-D array as an argument to a function but i try all of them and they give the same type of error. Please anyone help me out to remove this error. Actually i use this function in [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bomber-man/problem?h_r=internal-search) problem of hackerrank.

Comment: What does grid_2 look like?

Comment: Can I ask what grid_2 is??

Comment: Are you using a non-standard dynamic array and passing that?  That's what that error looks like.  If you are, either learn to use `std::vector<std::vector<>>`, or declare a standard, non-dynamic 2D array.

Comment: @MarkMoretto you can see grid in the problem link i mentioned.

Comment: @YunfeiChen i mention the hackerrank problem link you can see there.

Comment: @deepjashan2020 -- Why must we go to a link when it takes a few keystrokes to add the definition of `grid_2` here?  And yes, your problem is [what I described](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8025dc3d373e784).  Do you see the warnings about using that kind of syntax?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes the error which is shown in the link you attach is the same i faced on my machine. And the thing of the link is only to tell about the problem i want to solve, sorry for that..

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie And yes the thing you said above about the non-standard dynamic array, yes it is. But when i try ```std::vector<string> grid``` I didn't get any output at all.

Comment: Then your program has a bug, which is not the same issue as the compiler error.

Comment: Keep in mind that when you do vector<string> grid you are declaring a one dimensional array, you need to do vector<vector<string> > grid to declare a two dimension array.

Comment: Also how does your program know what r and c are?? I do not see them declared....

Comment: @YunfeiChen i actually ask a small part of my program here, r and c are declared as global variables.

Comment: @YunfeiChen i see the code in the hackerrank but they use only ```vector<string>grid```

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think so i search for all types of solution on the internet so that i can remove this bug and use many different calling techniques but noting helps.

Comment: Well cause its weird that what you are declaring only works if each instance of the vector is a vector by itself which is not what you want it will make the program more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: To be honest, this issue is due to you not knowing how to print a vector of `std::string`.  You don't need a nested loop, as you have with a 2-dimensional character array.  Just a simple `std::vector<std::string> sVector; for (auto& s : sVector ) std::cout << s << "\n";`.  Sites such as hackerrank assume you know the language that you're using when you write solutions -- it isn't meant to teach how to write proper code in C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i know about the printing vector of strings but the main question here i want to ask is how to pass a char array to a function and not about the vectors. Like its a simple task but the error i got is very different.

Comment: You got the answer on how to pass a character array.  The issue is that you cannot pass the fake 2D dynamic arrays you're declaring.  That's why you should be using a different type.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok i understand the array i passed should be of the specific size if i want to use it as char array, for dynamic array i can should use vectors.<br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you want a method to be valid for any matrix since you need to use char**. I is more cumbersome because if you are using pointers, but it is more flexible.

```
void final_output(char** arr, int nrow, int ncol) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ncol; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //construct the matrix (any size would work)
    int nrow = 10;
    int ncol = 20;
    char** arr = new char* [nrow];
    for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++){arr[i] = new char[ncol];}
    
    //assign values
    for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ncol; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = 'a';
        }
    }

    final_output(arr,nrow,ncol);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this works super fine for my problem. Just one thing to know only by declaring as ```char** arr``` is not enough, you do another initialization using ```new``` keyword?

Comment: yes, this are pointers pointing to an array of pointers so you need the new keyword. If you do not want to use pointers (they are cumbersome to use) you can use ```vector<vector<char>> ``` like some other people have suggested before.

Answer (score 1):

It is a strange function but it works for me assuming you define r and c, and the grid2 is an char[][200].

```
void final_output(char arr[][200]) {
    int i, j;
    int r = 10;
    int c = 200;
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char arr[10][200];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = 'a';
        }
    }
    final_output(arr);
    //it prints aaaaaaaa
}
```

Comment: Here actually you declare the size of char array in function as arr[ ] [200] and also pass the array of same size while calling the function. But i face a different problem, size may vary on different outputs, so the error i mentioned is something to do with the variable length of array.

Comment: if the argument of your function is ```char[][200] ``` you can only use  ```char[n][200] ``` data types as inputs. If you want the method to be valid for any possible matrix size, maybe you can consider using char** data types instead and then pass the nrow, ncol to the method as an argument.  ```void final_output(char** arr, int nrow,int ncol)```